# How to integrate validation engine js with jQuery AJAX and PHP email submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I am using from https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

The validation worked, but AJAX didn't work...
The problem is that it didn't work to me many times, i tried to do it but it failed more than 30 times, i don't know why, his AJAX submit php example isn't useful to me...

There is my script to validate the form:

```
    $("#formID").validationEngine({promptPosition : "centerRight", scroll: false, ajaxFormValidation: true});
```

There is my jQuery AJAX script that i want to integrate with Validation Engine:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send.php",
    data: sendData,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#ajax").show();
    },
    success: function () {

        $('#listo').html("<p>Thank you!</p>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1000, function () {

        });
    }
});
```

And there another my PHP script to send data form:

```
function send_email() {
$message = "\nNombre: " . $_POST['nombre'] .
    "\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'] .
    "\nMensaje: " . $_POST['message'] .
    "\nTélefono: " . $_POST['tel'];

$message .= "\n\nBrowser Info: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] .
    "\nIP: " . $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] .
    "\n\nDate: " . date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

$siteEmail = 'my@mail.com';
$emailTitle = 'Contact from your website';
$thankYouMessage = "succesful sent.";   

if(! mail($siteEmail, $emailTitle, $message, 'From: ' . $_POST['nombre'] . ' <' . $_POST['email'] . '>'))
    echo 'cannot send...';
```

}

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this out:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#formID").validationEngine({
        promptPosition: "centerRight",
        scroll: false,
        ajaxFormValidation: true,
        ajaxFormValidationURL: "send.php",
        onBeforeAjaxFormValidation: function () {
            $("#ajax").show();
        },
        onAjaxFormComplete: function () {
            $('#listo').html("<p>Thank you!</p>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
});
```